# (SQL Server Analysis Services) MDX query to get immediate parent?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, olap-cube, sql-server-2012-datatools

### Desired result

**When a cube is deployed and browsed, I wish to see only an immediate manager of an employee.**

The cube result shows all managers of a paticular employee, like below:

> Abbas, Sanchez, 825
>   Abbas, Welcker, 825
>   Abbas, Abbas, 825`

I want to see **only the immediate manager** of a paticular employee, meaning this:

> Abbas, Welcker, 825

### How to replicate the scenario:

1. Using *SQL Server Data Tools*
2. Create a *Analysis Services Multidimensional Data Mining Project*
3. Data Source is *AdventureWorksDW12* database, the sample database from Microsoft.
4. Data Source View have two tables: *FactResellerSales* and *DimEmployee*
5. Create a cube. *FactResellerSales* = measures. *DimEmployee* = dimensions.
6. *DimEmployee* dimention has the following attributes: *EmployeeKey, LastName, ParentEmployeeKey*.

   - *EmployeeKey* attribute is modified to take Name Column: DimEmployee.LastName
   - *ParentEmployeeKey* attribute is in parent-child relationship. The attribute has created a hierarchy of multi-level.[SCREENSHOT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWcRs.png)
7. Deploy cube and browse. Drag the following attributes: *LastName, ParentEmployeeKey, Order Quantity.* [SCREENSHOT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/up1dG.png)

Comment: Your question is lacking some of the required information. Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Will. I edited my post. Let me know if you have an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try either of these `mdx` functions:

`.Parent`  ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145513.aspx

`ancestor` ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145616.aspx

The context of the query in which you are trying to get the parent is important. What I mean is depending on what else you require on rows and columns or in the slicer will impact the way you use `mdx` to find the parent.

Something like the following may work:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.ParentKey AS 
   [Dim Employee].[Parent Employee Key].CurrentMember.Parent.member_caption
SELECT 
  {[Measures].ParentKey } ON 0,
  [Dim Employee].[Parent Employee Key].[(All)].members ON 1
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I had to switch rows and columns (ON 1, then ON 0) but it works.